# Java Write File in Linux

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

I need to write file and append content when I tried on windwos and file successfully written and append the content as well but when it comes to linux environment I can't see any file created and no error or exception as well.

This is how I write file on windows this workes

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(dynamicJson, HashMap.class);

String keys = map.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
String values = map.values().stream().map(obj -> 
String.valueOf(obj)).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
   

   
File file = new File("D:\\report-temp.csv");



try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\report-temp.csv", true);
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {


    if (file.length() == 0) {
        out.println(keys);
        out.println(values);

    } else {
        out.println(values);
    }


} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

when I run this on linux I've changed file location as `/home/xx/hashan/` but I no file created on linux.

Comment: Do not leave the catch block empty! At the very least, add an `e.printStackTrace()` in there. It will print the error.

Comment: ... and maybe switch to `java.nio`, it's very handy for simple file i/o operations.

Answer (score 6):

> I can't see any file created and no error or exception as well.

You're mistaken; there is an error.

> `} catch (IOException e) {}`

but you actually went out of your way to write code to ignore them!

Don't do that. Get rid of that catch entirely. If you then get compiler errors that you need to handle that exception, add `throws IOException` to the method signature. Keep adding those until the errors go away (that'll happen once you add `throws IOException` to your `main` method, which you should do.

The problem is probably related to a missing directory or access rights, which the exception you get will make obvious, so all you need to do is remove that silly line of code.

Comment: oh yea I made silly mistake I've omitted print the exception. Thanks!